# An android virtual device trouble

Tags: android

I am trying to develop the first application in android. after all code is written ,when i was trying to test that application on the androids virtual device.i.e emulator, it is not getting load.it showing only loading process.so tell me how to test this application or how to solve this problem.

Comment: You need to wait for some time for the emulator to get loaded

Comment: waiting since from 4hrs

Comment: Just close emulator and follow the answer that mentioned by Ashwin s Ashok

Comment: can you attach a screen shot of how you configured your virtual device in avd manager.In avd manager selecting the device and clicking on edit you can see the configurations.

Answer (score 2):

Try to edit the Settings of Emulator.
Vm Heap Size, Ram Size etc..

Or

Use Tools like BlueStacks or GenyMotions.

http://www.bluestacks.com/app-player.html

http://www.genymotion.com/

Comment: How do you increase a 2.3 genymotion emulator memory heap size? Thanks.